# How does one calculate the probability of a multivariate Gaussian in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

How does one calculate the probability of a multivariate Gaussian at point `x` in Scipy?

I tried

```
    probability = multivariate_normal(x, mean, v)
```

where `x`, `mean`, `v` are all correctly sized vectors, but I get:

```
    probability = multivariate_normal(x, mean, v )
TypeError: __call__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: sorry, corrected. do you think the pdf is the answer evaluated at point x  `  probability = multivariate_normal(x, mean, v).pdf(x)`

Comment: I know enough to recognize the words, and once upon 30 years ago, I might have done this sort of statistics, but not since then.  Have you looked at the [multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) documentation.  Most of them seem to use keywords.  I'm still not sure about the 'takes 3 (4 given)'; that has me puzzled, but I'm at best a mediocre Python programmer.

Comment: Without knowing what your inputs are, it's a guessing game to reproduce the error and help you.  Make it easy for others to help you by providing sample input that reproduces the problem you're seeing.  For me, `random.multivariate_normal([1], [[1]], [1])` returns `array([[ 0.65565737]])` which works just fine.  Note that the result of this function is generally not a probability (you're assigning it to a variable called `probability`), it's a random sample from the distribution.

Comment: how do i get the actual probability at point x and not a sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First the error. When you call `multivariate_normal` you are actually calling  `__call__` of the `multivariate_normal_gen` class ([source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py) at row 555). Which since it is a method takes itself, `self`, as an argument which always is the first argument. When you then add three more arguments the total number of arguments is four.

Regarding your question, you evaluate the probability density function at given point(s) by calling `pdf` of `multivariate_normal`. Example:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=[0, 1], cov=[5, 2])
```

Which prints out:

```
Out[44]: array([ 0.0354664 ,  0.00215671])
```

Comment: but a probability should  be a single value(0-1) regardless the number of variables/ dimensionality of the Gaussian

Comment: If you do `probs = multivariate_normal.pdf([[1,2], [3,4]], mean=[0, 1], cov=[5, 2])`, then `probs[0]` = P(x,y = 1,2) and `probs[1]` = P(x,y=3,4). The output is the sequence of probabilities for each element of the input array, which each is a single value in the interval [0,1].

Comment: This is incorrect. The pdf needs to be integrated over a multidimensional range to get a probability. This is simply the likelihood.

Comment: @NateM can you show how to integrate pdf over the multidimensional range?